# InheritanceType.JOINED strategy not working in with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have problem implementing InheritanceType.JOINED strategy with hibernate.

All the time I got this kind of exception:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:348) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Table school_service.abstract_person not found
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getTableId(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5118) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.<init>(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:433) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

I created a Spring Boot / Gradle project to replicate the bug here: https://github.com/tamershahin/JoinTableTest

this is the Main Class:

```
 @Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "person_type")
@Table(name = "abstract_person",schema = "school_service")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    @Column(name="person_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 125, name="name")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    String name;

   @Column(name = "person_type", nullable = false)
    @Getter@Setter
    String personType;

}
```

and this the one extending it:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("student")
@Table(name = "student_detail",schema = "school_service")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "person_id")
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student extends Person {

    @Column(length = 32, nullable = false)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    String email;

    @Column(length = 32, nullable = false)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    String className;
}
```

essentially I'm following the JPA guidelines, and in fact if I switch to InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS strategy everything works, but that implementation is not what I need.

I debugged a bit the class: .../hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final-sources.jar!/org/hibernate/persister/entity/AbstractEntityPersister.java

and I noticed that this bit of code:

```
for ( int j = 0; j < tables.length; j++ ) {
            if ( tableName.equalsIgnoreCase( tables[j] ) ) {
                return j;
            }
        }
```

never returns the right table because tableName always contains the schema and tables don't.. that's why it's not able to find the table.

Is it me misconfiguring / misusing something or is this a proper bug?

Thanks folks.

T

**EDIT:**

I'm using this property:

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

so the DB should be generated by Hibernate on his needing, but everything crashes before it.

I also tried to create the class manually as explained here:
http://www.javaroots.com/2013/07/hibernate-inheritance-joined-strategy.html

but no success.

UPDATE:
After @crafarlo comment I start playing with application.properties and I found that removing this config:

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema

will do the trick.

This is my full config:

```
urlwithoutschema=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
spring.datasource.url=${urlwithoutschema}${spring.datasource.schema}
spring.datasource.username=school
spring.datasource.password=school
spring.datasource.schema=school_service
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=${spring.datasource.schema}
```

I don't see why this will affect the mapping class-tables, but it does.. any clue?

Comment: What has "@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)" got to do with JOINED?!

Comment: Sorry, my fault: you're right the code I copy-pasted here was from another a test project working with TABLE_PER_CLASS.

BUT the code shared on github is the correct one. 

And I confirm that JOINED is not working.

Comment: @Tamer check my response, you forgot the discriminator column in the abstract class. Hibernate is not so smart to do it alone :)

Comment: @cralfaro: I test with and without the column declared explicitly, I read somewhere that with hibernate autogenerate it's not needed to do it. 
I'm updating git and post code to reflect the fact that is NOT working with or without discriminator column declared. Good catch though :)

Comment: @Tamer try this changes...Add the schema in all your entities, use the same column name for the primary key in all tables, in this case "Person_id" just to simplify the case

Comment: @Tamer maybe because you define a schema name in a global way but also in some other entity i saw the schema attribute, maybe that confuse hibernate

Answer (score 0):

> Table school_service.abstract_person not found

The Table school_service.abstract_person is missing. This one was not necessary with TABLE_PER_CLASS but with JOINED you need a table for every entity in the hierarchy.

Comment: I'm asking hibernate to create the table for now, this is the strange bit.. everything fails when it's time to create them and this happens only with InheritanceType.JOINED

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing a Inheritance by JOIN. You should use this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "person_type")
@Table(name = "abstract_person",schema = "school_service")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class Person {
     @Id
     @Getter
     @Setter
     @Column(name = "ID")
     @GeneratedValue(...)
     private Integer id; 
     //...



@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("student")
@Table(name = "student_detail",schema = "school_service")
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student extends Person {

    @Column(length = 32, nullable = false)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    String email;

    @Column(length = 32, nullable = false)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    String className;
}
```

And in your subclass-table define the PK which is the same as in the main table. Then the join will work

UPDATE:

You also forgot to add the discriminator column in the abstract class

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "person_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)

...

@Getter @Setter
@Column(name = "person_type", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
private String type;
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault: you're right the code I copy-pasted here was from a test project working with TABLE_PER_CLASS.

BUT the code shared on github is the correct one. 

And I confirm that JOINED is not working.

Comment: I tried your code, specifying the column and setting the @Enumerated annotation. I also declared an Enum to hold STUDENT and TEACHER values. still not working.. is git code working for you?

Comment: @Tamer I didn't try it, is not in memory and i dont want to recreate my schema now :), i have the exactly same situation working tell me your email and i will share the example with you

Comment: after your clue on in memory config working I started playing wiht config as per update and now it's working.. thanks! would be nice to know why :D

p.s.: i confirm that in the domain class you don't need the discriminator column declared.

Answer (score 0):

Remove schema = "school_service" from @Table, it should resolve your problem.

From

```
@Table(name = "abstract_person",schema = "school_service")
```

To

```
@Table(name = "abstract_person")
```

### AbstractEntityPersister.class:3765

Because, in this code Hibernate try to compare "school_service.abstract_person" with "abstract_person".

```
public static int getTableId(String tableName, String[] tables) {
    for(int j = 0; j < tables.length; ++j) {
        if (tableName.equalsIgnoreCase(tables[j])) {
            return j;
        }
    }

    throw new AssertionFailure("Table " + tableName + " not found");
}
```

This is why you have this error:

***Table school_service.abstract_person not found***

Comment: this led me in the right direction! in my case I had `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema` set in application.properties. Make sure to remove that as well! Otherwise, it is the equivalent to `@Table(schema = "school_service")` for every @Table annotation.